# Custom Payfort screen for IOS React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, view, xib, payfort

I am using Payfort for React Native with this [React Native Payfort SDK Library](https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-payfort-sdk) all things are working good but I want to customize the screen for IOS.

I've read the documentation from PayFort but I can't find View file for reference the image or anything.

I've PayFortView2.xib when I edit some color or text it's ok but when I try to add Image the doest not showing when I run the app I am not familiar with Xcode or Xib files.

please help me

Comment: It seems all the screens are part of PayFortSDK.framework which is a dependency to the React Native package.

Comment: when you go into the ios directory there is PayFortView2.xib file is available I try to change the things in xcode but only color is changing i can't be able to anything new like image nothing else

Answer (score 1):

you can edit natively with PayFortSDK.framework for iOS.

or you can go for Custom Merchant Method design your own Ui in react native. it runs perfectly